# Find the longest Elements in a 2d array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm currently working with a 2d Array which is 6 rows long.

Now I need to filter the longest rows to work with them. But I dont know how to filter the shortest the element.

For example:

```
0: (3) ['karo11', 'karo6', 'kreuz13']
1: (2) ['pik6', 'pik13']
2: ['karo13']
3: (2) ['herz11', 'kreuz6']
4: ['herz6']
5: (2) ['kreuz11', 'pik11']
```

This is my array. Now I need to filter out row 2 and 4. But how should I do this?

Note. The Array is not static so the length of the rows are variable and change everytime I run the code

Comment: do you need to filter the longest or the shortest? Type out your input and expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Math.max()` and `Math.min()` to get the max and min length element from the array and then you can filter that out based on the requirement.

**Demo :**

```js
const inputArr = [
  ['karo11', 'karo6', 'kreuz13'],
  ['pik6', 'pik13'],
  ['karo13'],
  ['herz11', 'kreuz6'],
  ['herz6'],
  ['kreuz11', 'pik11']
];

let shortest = inputArr.filter(i => i.length !== Math.max(...inputArr.map(i => i.length)))

let longest = inputArr.filter(i => i.length !== Math.min(...inputArr.map(i => i.length)))

console.log(shortest)
console.log(longest)
```

Comment: could you explain me why there are three dots after the Math.max function?

Comment: As map function always return a new array. Hence, we used spread operator to use map returned result as a new array.

Answer (score 2):

One way might be to get the length of each array, find the minimum length and then filter the array where length is not equal to the minimum.

And if you need to filter out the max lengths, use `Math.max()` instead.

```js
let arr = [
  ['karo11', 'karo6', 'kreuz13'],
  ['pik6', 'pik13'],
  ['karo13'],
  ['herz11', 'kreuz6'],
  ['herz6'],
  ['kreuz11', 'pik11']
]


let min = Math.min(...arr.map(i => i.length))

let result = arr.filter(i => i.length !== min)

console.log(result)
```